# Formula for diagonal measurement over and back down a wall

Tags: geometry

Is there a formula to solve the following problem?

You stand "a" away from a "b" high wall. You can fly distance "c" and have to end on the ground again.

When "a", "b" and "c" are known,and "a" is < "c", is there a formula to calculate **"n" the longest distance on the ground plane** you traveled from your starting point to your landing?
Bonus question: Does the location of the wall matter? I think so, but not sure.

**My attempt:**
The distance to get up the wall is a<sup>2</sup>+b<sup>2</sup>=d<sup>2</sup>. So then we still have c-(d<sup>1/2</sup>)=c<sub>rest</sub> movement to get down.

We already moved "a" horizontally.
m<sup>2</sup>=c<sub>rest</sub><sup>2</sup>-b<sup>2</sup>
a+d<sup>1/2</sup>=**n**

Is my attempt correct, and is there a simplified formula for this, so that I can just punch in the numbers and let it compute?

Thanks. (If anyones interested, this is not homework but for a Tabletop game :D).

Comment: In "My attempt" it should be $d$, not $d^{1/2}$.  Now use the same formula on the other side, using the remaining fly distance as $d$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. What I think you're asking is this: you want to traverse a wall of height $b$ which is $a$ units away from you. You have the capacity to "fly" a total distance $c$ before you must stop (i.e. your movement can be described by a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of arc length $c$). Assuming that you must cross to the other side of the wall during your flight, and that you must end your flight path back on the ground, what is the maximum distance from your original starting location that you can land?

In order to maximize the distance you travel, you are going to want to fly in straight lines. You're right that to get to the top of the wall, you will need to fly $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ units, since that's the length of the hypotenuse of the right triangle between you and the wall. After that, you'll have $c-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ more units that you can fly. If you don't have to land back on the ground, then you can just fly $c-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ units directly away from your starting position (after which you will presumably drop to the ground), for a total distance covered of $a+c-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. If you do have to return to the ground, then you better hope that $c$ is large enough, because it might not be big enough to get back down from the top of the wall! In order to traverse the wall and land safely on the ground on the other side, $c$ needs to be at least as large as $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+b$. If $c$ was exactly $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+b$, that would give you just enough flight time to fly directly down the other side of the wall once you reached the top and land on the ground.

Supposing that $c$ is large enough, getting as far as possible from your starting position is going to mean using the whole rest of the flight time you have left once you reach the top of the wall (which should be $c-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$) to fly along the hypotenuse of a right triangle oriented orthogonal to the wall, with its other leg on the ground. One leg of this right triangle runs up the wall and so has length $b$. The other leg runs along the ground, call its length $d$. So the Pythagorean theorem tells us that $b^2+d^2=(c-\sqrt{a^2+b^2})^2$. Rearranging gives $d = \sqrt{(c-\sqrt{a^2+b^2})^2-b^2}$. Since you traversed $a$ units along the ground before crossing the wall, your total travel distance from your starting position (again, assuming you move directly away) is going to be $a + d$, or in other words $a + \sqrt{(c-\sqrt{a^2+b^2})^2-b^2}$.

Hopefully I did not make any mistakes in the algebra here.

Edit: because you probably do not want to pause your tabletop game for a long time to do math, [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dy9w6rstxa) is a desmos calculator that will calculate the total travel distance ($t$) if you input $a$, $b$, and $c$. If $t$ says "undefined", that's because your flight time $c$ is not actually large enough to traverse the wall and land back safely on the ground.